# Clear BitMap Cache - koush ion

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, ion-koush

i would like to clear bitmap cache but i am not sure how to clear the bit map . 
I am using Koush Ion library to load the picture

```
try {
            bitmap = Ion.with(context).load(URLimage).withBitmap().asBitmap().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i need to clear the bitmap cache everytime i click on a button. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use `Ion.getDefault(context).getCache().clear()` to clear the file cache.

Use `Ion.getDefault(context).getBitmapCache().clear()` to clear the in-memory bitmap cache.

See the source for the respective methods at:
https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/blob/master/AndroidAsync/src/com/koushikdutta/async/util/FileCache.java#L292
https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/bitmap/IonBitmapCache.java#L63

`Ion.dump()` will NOT clear the cache. It will simply print some debug information to the log. You can look up the source code for it, too.

Answer (score 1):

try this may help,,i used this code for clearing my network data cache;

Ion.getDefault(context).configure().getResponseCache().clear()